# What is better for performance creating Function or instance of the constructor Function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

Does calling a function take the same resources and time, as creating an instance of the constructor function in javascript node v8.5.0?

I find that they give me the same result, as:

```
var repo = function () {

var db = {};

var get = function (id) {
    console.log('Getting task ' + id);
    return {
        name: 'new task from db'
    }
 }

var save = function (task) {
    console.log('Saving ' + task.name + ' to the db');
 }

console.log('newing up task repo');
return {
    get: get,
    save: save
 }

}
 module.exports = repo();
```

When I replace `module.exports = repo();` with `module.exports = new repo;` it gives me the same result, but I need to know which one is better performance wise.

Comment: IMHO, it doesn't matter because you will only have a small amount of repo objects; ideally one. You will only make `repo()` or `new repo` once.

Comment: The difference is so minimal as not to be worth worrying about. You should rather decide how exactly you want your function to be used. `new` or no `new`?

Comment: if so, what is the best practice you use @deceze ?

Comment: I would write a `class` instead of this kind of module constructor function, which would then be used with `new`. But I would probably not export a singleton with no chance of instantiating another instance; there's simply no use for enforcing singletoness to that degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function does return an object already, it is not a constructor (that initialises an instance through the `this` keyword) in the traditional sense and *should not be called with `new`*. It doesn't even matter whether that is faster or slower - just don't do it. (Hint: `new` would probably be slower, as it has to create a new instance from `repo.prototype` and then throw it away).

And of course there's no good reason to use a function at all in this case. You're only calling it once anyway, so you could inline the code:

```
const db = {};
function get(id) {
    console.log('Getting task ' + id);
    return {
        name: 'new task from db'
    }
}
function save(task) {
    console.log('Saving ' + task.name + ' to the db');
}
console.log('newing up task repo');
module.exports = {
    get,
    save
};
```

or even simplify to

```
const db = {};
exports.get = function (id) {
    console.log('Getting task ' + id);
    return {
        name: 'new task from db'
    };
};
exports.save = function (task) {
    console.log('Saving ' + task.name + ' to the db');
};
console.log('newing up task repo');
```

Answer (score 0):

by using `module.exports = repo();` you are calling repo function and assigning the return value into `module.export`, here in `this` will point to the same memory instance

hence by using `module.exports = new repo;` first you are creating new instance and assigning the new instance to the  `module.export` in this method `this` will be different memory instance.

so the simple terms it's all depends upon the use-case how are are going to use your code by pointing the same instance or by creating the new instance.

I hope you understand the architecture.